# Trying a different approach for Projet Euler Problem 8

Tags: java, numbers

So I'm new to Java and I'm trying a different solution for [Project Euler Problem 8](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8). In this I have used `BigInteger` class datatype to store the  1000-digit number but I'm not able to traverse the particular values at any index or multiply it like I'm trying. Although I was able to do it with `String`, I want to try this method. It would be a great help.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class newexp{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger myBigInteger = new BigInteger(
                "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\n" +
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\n" +
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\n" +
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\n" +
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\n" +
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\n" +
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\n" +
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\n" +
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\n" +
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\n" +
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\n" +
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\n" +
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\n" +
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\n" +
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\n" +
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\n" +
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\n" +
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\n" +
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\n" +
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450\n" +
                "\n");

        long s = 0;
        int n = 1000;
        long maxval = 0;
        long currval = 1;
        for (int i = 13; i <= n; i++){
            for (long j = s; j <= 13; j++){
                currval *= myBigInteger.valueOf(s);
            }
            s++;
        }
        if (maxval < currval){
            maxval = currval;
        }

        System.out.println(maxval);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need BigInteger for this.  The long's are sufficient to hold the product.

```
public class BigFib {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String bigNum =
                "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                        + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                        + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                        + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                        + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                        + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                        + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                        + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                        + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                        + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                        + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                        + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                        + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                        + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                        + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                        + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                        + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                        + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                        + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                        + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

        int n = bigNum.length();
        int start = 0;
        long maxval = 0;

        // count from 0 to the length of the string less 13.      
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 13; i++) {

        // now starting at the first character, start taking the product of the
        // digits.
            long currval = 1;
            for (int j = i; j < i+13; j++) {
                // subtracting '0' from digit converts it to 
                // to an 'int'
                currval *= (bigNum.charAt(j) - '0');
            }

            // if the current value is > maxval, assign to maxval
            if (maxval < currval) {
                maxval = currval;
                start = i;
            }
        }
        // now print the maxproduct and the string of digits.
        System.out.println(maxval);
        System.out.println("digits = " + bigNum.substring(start,start+13));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank u so much , for taking ur time and solving it , I didn't knew subtracting with zero converts string to int